# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SimpleViewController getDataFromTwitter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c31a70'

Tags: ios, xcode4

I know that some people with this problem had issues managing view controller memory, but I only have a single page app, and one of the other IBAction buttons in the view invokes its method just fine, so I don't think memory management is the issue.

When I try respondsToSelector: in viewDidLoad (shown below), I get the error "use of undeclared identifier 'getDataFromTwitter'.

**Here is the SimpleViewController.m . . .**

```
#import "SimpleViewController.h"

@interface SimpleViewController ()
@property NSString *name;
@end

@implementation SimpleViewController

@synthesize dataReceiptNotification;
@synthesize score;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize outputTextView;
@synthesize nameTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self respondsToSelector:getDataFromTwitter:];
}


- (IBAction)getDataFromTwitter:(UIButton *)sender {
     . . .
}
```

**And the SimpleViewController.h . . .**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

@interface SimpleViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataReceiptNotification;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *score;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *outputTextView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;


- (IBAction)getDataFromTwitter:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)calculateScore:(id)sender;

@end
```

*I wonder if the issue was caused by the storyboard setup?  I may have changed the method name at some point.
Thank you in advance.*

Comment: what for you are calling `respondsToSelector`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
[self respondsToSelector:getDataFromTwitter:];
```

It should be:

```
[self respondsToSelector:@selector(getDataFromTwitter:)];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, that gets rid of my compile error.  Thank you.  My bad.  But I was only calling respondsToSelector: to verify that the method was not recognized even though it is there in the view controller.  But, apparently it is recognized.  So now I am doubly confused as to why I get the runtime error.  Perhaps it is something simple -- I am pretty new to iOS. Perhaps there is some memory thing I am not clear about?

Comment: Just to clarify: you still get the `-[SimpleViewController getDataFromTwitter]: unrecognized selector sent` runtime error?

Comment: Yes, @qegal, I still get the unrecognized selector runtime error.